# min-height and height are not working as auto while adding the position: absolute;

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/zvdktc63/1/

blue box = carousel
red = slide

Absolute Position div not pushing other content down.

`height:auto` and `min-height:auto` are not working with the `position: absolute`.

Looking **min-height** and **height** should work as auto so content will push down while adding the position: absolute.

```
<div class="parent">

<div class="child">
scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds scsd scds 
</div>


</div>
<div class="next">

</div>

.child {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.next {
  background: blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
   word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see wrong ! can explain little more what you want ?

Comment: the parent div is relative and the child div is absolute and need to add min-height="200px" to the parent div, and after adding more content in the child div then it is not working as heigt="auto" behavior.


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
  typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>


.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}